# target/build CFLAGS mixup when cross-emerging due to bug or my stupidity?

Tags: compiling, gentoo, cross-compilation, configure

I'm trying to emerge LLVM using emerge from a crossdev (for ARM) overlay in Gentoo. I've set the CFLAG of the overlay to optimise for arm (-march=armv6j), which seems to make ./configure fail on the "checking for executable suffix on build platform" with the message "error: installation or configuration problem: compiler cannot create executables" due to "bad value (armv6j) for -march= switch"; suggesting that it is trying to use the CFLAGS of the crossdev overlay even when not cross compiling.

My question is if this is most likely due to a bug in the ebuild/package/llvm or due to me being silly (as far as I've been able to tell LLVM should be pretty cross compilable)? I've pasted the relevant output/logs [here](http://pastebin.com/RBfjMbVi), in case they turn out to clarify anything.